# Selenium cookies, which must have name and value values

Tags: liferay

Add_cookie (cookie_dict): Add cookie. "Cookie_dict" refers to a dictionary object, which must have name and value values.
F12 cookies do not have a direct name and value in the pages visited.
Is it the first key in cookies, right?

Comment: northeast normal university

Comment: nanjing university